# File class private method open in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, production

Given the following method:

```
def import_photos
  require 'fileutils'
  File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'fotos.zip'), "wb") do |f|
    f.write(params[:zipfile].read)
  end
  CamperPhoto.delay.import_photos
  redirect_to admin_campers_path, notice: "Afbeeldingen verwerken"
end
```

I'm simply uploading a zip-file and processing the images inside of it.

Locally this works fine. Through a rake task, this works fine. However, when trying to upload it in production through a form I'm seeing this error in my production log:

```
NoMethodError (private method `open' called for #<Class:0xc0700d8>):
  app/controllers/spina/admin/campers_controller.rb:40:in `import_photos'
```

Comment: It looks like `open` is being called on a singleton class instead of the `File` class. Can you reproduce this if you run it in production mode locally?

Comment: Running in production mode locally results in the same error message.

Comment: Fixed it! I was calling File from within my Spina module which is an engine. Calling ::File.open solved the problem. How come this only occurs in production mode?

Comment: Not sure why this would only happen in production mode. Must have to do with the way things are loaded. Glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Was calling File.open from within my own module. Calling the ::File.open solved it for me.

```
def import_photos
  require 'fileutils'
  ::File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'fotos.zip'), "wb") do |f|
    f.write(params[:zipfile].read)
  end
  CamperPhoto.delay.import_photos
  redirect_to admin_campers_path, notice: "Afbeeldingen verwerken"
end
```